# IntPtr vs ref C#

Tags: c#

i have to import unmanaged dll into my C# application,
I want to know what is the diferent between IntPtr and ref, and what you recommnded me to use and why?
Note that both ways are working to me.
For example:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern Result Init(IntPtr versionInfo);

 [DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern Result Init(ref Version versionInfo);
```

Answer (score 5):

If `Version` is a struct that is compatible with the struct that the extern `Init` function expects, there is no significant difference between the two, except that the `ref` version will be a *lot* easier to use from C# since the runtime will manage all of the marshaling and pinning for you.  Unless you really want to do all that work, I would stick with the `ref` option.

Of course, without seeing the C function prototype, the `Version` struct in C#, and the struct used in C for that parameter, I can really only guess.

Comment: There is one potentially significant difference: using IntPtr allows passing IntPtr.Zero as a value, while `ref Version` does not. Thus, it's not unusual to need the IntPtr overload, depending on what the native code requires.

Comment: @jonp: In that case, you'd want **both** versions (an overloaded function), so you can pass a `Version` by reference when you have one, and `IntPtr.Zero` when you want to pass null.  Or make `Version` a class instead of a struct, then you can pass null (and no longer need the `ref` keyword, but p/invoke annotation attributes are then needed on the class).

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Based on some criticism forcing me to rethink this and research it further. I freely admit that IntPtr is error prone, I think there may be some debate on what "harder" means, but if the framework can marshall it automagically and keep you from having to pin things, etc if you do not use IntPtr then I think I am in agreement that IntPtr would be "harder. It appears to me after further research and thought that it would be easier (when you are forced to P/Invoke and can't make a C++/CLI wrapper) to declare your struct (in your case Version) in the managed code and then pass it via the ref parameter.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Version
{
    // Data members
}

[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Result Init(ref Version versionInfo);
```

<strike>My guess would be you would want the IntPtr version. The difference is that IntPtr is a class that manages a pointer to memory, whereas declaring a parameter as a reference (ref keyword) in an argument list means that you are passing by reference. In general when passing data to and from an unmanaged dll via a P/Invoke call, unless the data being passed is a vanilla type (int, double, string - with appropriate Marshal decoration) I pass data as an IntPtr. You can then Marshal the IntPtr to your managed declaration of the unmanaged struct.</strike>

You should check out this link for more information on P/Invoke calls:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Comment: It's unfortunate that you're doing things the hard, error-prone way.  It's even more unfortunate that you are teaching other people to do so as well.

Comment: @Ben I am happy to learn an easier/less error prone way to do it. Do you have a link or suggested reading material. I don't spend a lot of time P/Invoking things, most of the time I write a C++/CLI wrapper, but when I have come down to having to P/Invoke I have only used ref parameters for things like int, string (StringBuilder in come cases), etc, and then used IntPtr for the other things.

Comment: C++/CLI for the win :)  For those occasions when you can't use it (Windows CE, or can't be sure that the Visual C++ runtime will be installed), then http://pinvoke.net has an awful lot of examples.  Generally, not only the primitive types like `int` and `double` can be safely used in p/invoke signatures, but also user-defined types made up of primitive types.  Examples would be `POINT`, `POINTF`, `RECT`, `FONTMETRIC`, `BITMAPFILEHEADER`, etc.

Comment: @Ben looks like I was writing my new rant while you were helping, my bad! Thanks for the info, I actually refer to pinvoke.net when I need to do an API level thing and must P/Invoke it. I think I understand what you are getting at, I read another article pointing out the ability to declare the struct in a managed environment (with the SequentialLayout attribute) and then let the environment marshall that with a "ref" keyword. Thanks for making me research a little further.

Answer (score 2):

IntPtr will let you move all your Externs to one class, without dependencies on the structures being used in the calls, which may be defined elsewhere. I like to keep the api adapter seperate from the data struct/class defs which seem more natural to put in the next layer.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use `IntPtr` because it will make your code more flexible when it comes to compiling the code to x64. `IntPtr` will expand its size automatically.

```
IntPtr = 4 bytes on x86
IntPtr = 8 bytes on x64
```

There are cases when certain types in C double they size when compiled for x64 but the C# counterparts (that are declared for PInvoke) don't. Then the function call will fail. If `Version` class contain some field like that then you better use `IntPtr`.

Comment: `ref` will pass a pointer-sized parameter as well.  The rest of your answer sounds like you're talking about the innards of the `Version` structure, not the parameter itself.  While it's possible that some of the fields of `Version` should have type `IntPtr`, that's no reason not to use `ref Version` in the p/invoke declaration.

Comment: @Ben You did not get the idea thought I think I expressed myself very well. I did not said that using ref will not work, but in my opinion I would have used IntPtr. But thanks for the down vote when you don't the answer.

Comment: @Liviu: I downvoted (and evidently I'm not the only one) because your answer is WRONG.  You said that "`IntPtr` will make your code more flexible" wrt pointer size, and this is simply false.  `ref` and `IntPtr` are the same size on every platform.

Comment: @Ben: It is you that are totally wrong. Check this link and convince yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx/ And all that gave me a down vote for this should check this link. I'm already getting tired of this.

Comment: @Liviu: I never said that the size of `IntPtr` doesn't change.  I said that a `ref` argument also gets converted to a pointer of the correct size.  So there is no advantage to using `IntPtr`.  It would be correct to say "`IntPtr` will make your code flexible wrt pointer size", but you said `IntPtr` will make your code **more** flexible wrt pointer size than `ref`, and that is wrong.

Comment: The second half of your answer is also wrong.  Using `IntPtr` as the function argument will not change the size of any field inside `Version`.  Only using `IntPtr` inside `Version` would do that, and that wouldn't show up in the p/invoke declaration at all.